# How do I upgrade my InfluxDB shell version?

Tags: raspberry-pi, influxdb

I have been searching the internet for a way to upgrade my InfluxDB shell version from version 1.6.4  to 1.8.6 on my Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2 (Yes it is ancient). My InfluxDB installation version is 1.8.6 and I read that if the InfluxDB and InfluxDB Shell versions are not the same then I will get parsing errors when using the CLI and I am.

Here is my version numbers on screenshot 1: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA7P7.jpg)

Here is  my attempt to update the InfluxDB shell version using the command `sudo apt install influxdb-client`: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Cj5.jpg)

As you can see in the image above that the InfluxDB Shell is already the latest version (1.6.4) but I saw that there is in fact a shell version 1.8.3 as seen in screenshot below(from a YouTube video).

Here is the how I want it: [correct shell version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYcG1.jpg)

If there is anyone that could help me I would appreciate it! This is also my first stack overflow question and I hope it is good enough : )

Answer (score 1):

The Debian/Ubuntu archives still have a very old version of InfluxDB in them. But you can get the latest from https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/

If you need 1.8 specifically (not 2.0), scroll down to the bottom of that page to the `Are you interested in InfluxDB 1.x Open Source?` section. There you can find ARM builds as tarballs you can download and extract. Both 32bit (armhf) and 64bit (arm64) builds are available.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I did not find the page which you linked above.